# Excel - How do I highlight a cell if its address is stored in a column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a worksheet with a list of 'Special Cells' in a column, like 'C352', 'E11', etc.

How do I write a conditional formatting rule that looks through the column on the other worksheet, and if that cell is in the column, color it a certain way? I know how to do the worksheet reference and the coloring, just not how to check it the cell reference is in the column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this as the conditional format formula

```
=MATCH(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),4,1),AddressList!$A:$A,0)
```

Where the sheet and column containing addresses is sheet `AddressList`, column `A`

How it works

- `ROW()` returns the row of the cell containing the formula (either in the cell itself, or in conditional formatting on the cell
- `COLUMN()` ditto for column
- `ADDRESS( r, c, 4, 1)` returns the address or row `r`, column `c`.  `4` means relative (ie no `$`'s.  `1` means `A1` style.  So `ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),4,1)` will be the address of the conditionally formatted cell in `A1` notation
- `MATCH(val, AddressList!$A:$A, 0)`  searches for `val` in range `AddressList!$A:$A`, 0 means exact match.  Returns row number if `val` is found, `#N/A` if not.
- Conditional format treats a possitive number as `True` and `#N/A` as false

Answer (score 1):

Based on your other question, I'd use a formula like:

```
=IF(SUBSTITUTE(CELL("address",INDIRECT($C$1)),"$",)=SUBSTITUTE(CELL("address",D4),"$",),1,0)
```

in your conditional format. This will format D4 (or whatever other cells you apply the conditional format to) based on whether C1 has a "D4" in it.

Comment: This will check every cell in the worksheet to see if it's in column D on worksheet2? So if D2 = 'C42' then cell C42 would be highlighted red?

Comment: For each cell you apply this conditional format to, it will highlight if its cell reference is in C1. So if you want to apply it to all cells in Column D, select Column D and enter the conditional format. You'd need to change the D4 to D1 though.